# Ubuntu 17.04 Suddenly Crashed And No Idea Why

Tags: 17.04, crash

I've had 17.04 running for months just fine. It's "Always-On" 24/7. It's set to automatically log on so there is never a log on screen during boot up should I reboot. Yesterday it was running perfect. I went to check the mail. When I returned, I was faced with the log in screen and even that was frozen. I rebooted numerous times. Here's what I get.

Black screen----maroon options screen----maroon blank screen----black screen----with message box.

Error:
(Click to dismiss. Also printed to stderr)
File error: No such file or directory, gnome

**The last change I made in Ubuntu**? With each new upgrade (17.04) I lose my sound, pulseaudio problems. Eventually it starts working if I just wait it out. A month ago I used Ubuntu Software Center to remove pulseaudio. After several minor updates over the past month and a reboot or two. I decided to use Ubuntu Software Center to reinstall pulseaudio. I had yet to reboot after performing this single task. It's been days since I made that install.

So anyways. I'm stuck flat footed not knowing where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simple stuff first...

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thank you for answering. Result? sudo:unable to resolve host shuftin: Connection refused. Over a year ago I changed the computer generated name of this Ubuntu to shuftin (my name). Sure there have been a few minor hic-ups concerning permissions with the new name. Could this be what's causing the current problem?

Comment: @Shuftin  Try just `fsck -f /` without the sudo. How did you change the computer name? Report back. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Answer (score 0):

Results. And BTW thanks.

Results. sudo: unable to resolve host shuftin: Connection refused

First, my name is Shuftin. A year or so ago I changed the computer generated name for my Ubuntu to Shuftin. Occasionally, very rarely, there is a hic-up about permissions pursuant to the new name. Nothing has ever been serious though. I managed to correct those. May this be what's posing the problem?

I'm still in the root system. Under the "Emergency Help" options. There is -p Automatic repair (no questions). -y Assume "yes" to all questions. And others.

Should I explore these?

Comment: @heynnema It's been so long ago I can't remember where I was or what I did to change the computer name. It really has not been much of an issue. I tried fsck -f/ without the sudo. I had to eliminate the "/" for it to work. I went through a whole list of yes/no questions. I said yes to everything and then rebooted. same 'ol same 'ol. Thank you for your attention.